# couchdb & futon - Is there a way to cancel a continuous replication using futon

Tags: couchdb, replication, couchdb-futon

Is there a way to cancel a continuous replication using futon ?

One of my developers started getting this funny error, when trying to replicate a template DB to his work environment.

```
Replicator failed:
{error,{'EXIT',{badarg,[{erlang,apply,[gen_server,start_link,undefined]},
      {supervisor,do_start_child,2},
      {supervisor,handle_call,3},
      {get_server,handle_msg,5},
      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}}}
```

After fiddling with it for a while, and testing I managed to reproduce the problem, I found that he probably checked by mistake the "continous" checkbox in the futon.

Now, we're working on windows. no magic curl thing. Well, obviously I can solve the problem for him from a linux, but I'm curious.

Is there a way to cancel a continuous replication using futon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete the appropriate replication document.

In futon you'll see a _replicator database.  Click on that and you'll see a list of docs.  Each doc is a one-way replication from a source to a target.  Find the offending one, and then just delete that document.  Couch will immediately stop the replication task.  It will not, however, remove any documents that were already replicated.

Comment: I found that this answer is correct only for v1.1 and up.
I had the problem on 1.0, however, migrated to 1.1 since then :)

Comment: Yes, replication has been a moving target. ;-)

Comment: I only have a deign document in the replication DB.